# Doorkeeper gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-code-401, doorkeeper

i am using doorkeeper gem

my ApplicationController look like this:

```
private
def current_resource_owner
    Person.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
end
```

my DemosController look like this:

```
doorkeeper_for :index
respond_to :json 
def index
    respond_with current_resource_owner
end
```

response comes like this:

```
Started GET "/?code=f88d2e95b1b286645d31772c395e0e36708a5i0p970836af640f631bb4f043b5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-28 11:10:56 +0530
Processing by DemosController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"code"=>"f88d2e95b1b286645d31135c395e0e36708a5b5b970836af640f631bb4f043b5"}
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0xb608b90@/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@verticalserver/gems/doorkeeper-1.0.0/lib/doorkeeper/helpers/filter.rb:8> rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Did you get to solve this issue? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an issue on Doorkeeper. To have a custom JSON response for 401 Unauthorized errors instead of a blank page, in ApplicationController I added:

```
def doorkeeper_unauthorized_render_options
  {json: '{"status": "failure", "message":"401 Unauthorized"}'}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question correctly. Your code looks fine, but the request seems to be wrong.

With Doorkeeper you need an Access Token and not the Code parameter to access the resource (DemosController#index). So first of all you have to get the Access Token from the Authorization Code. Therefore make a request

```
GET "/oauth/token?code=...&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=...&client_id=...&client_secret=..."
```

Make sure that the redirect_uri matches with the one registered with your client application and add the correct client_id and client_secret to the request. Also use always a fresh code parameter. Per default it is only valid for 10 minutes after generation. Notice, in case of customized Doorkeeper routes the url (/oauth/token) might be different.

If you done the request correctly, the response will contain a valid access token.

Then make a GET request to "/index.json?access_token=..." instead of "/?code=...". '.json' tells Rails your client can handle JSON. Otherwise you will get a 406 Response, which means that the requested format (by default HTML) is not supported. Instead of '.json' you can also send Accept="application/json" in the HTTP header.

The 401 Unauthorized response, what you're currently receiving, means that the authentication information (in your case a valid Access Token) is wrong or missing at all.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your respond_to also needs to respond to html because you are requesting "DemosController#index as HTML"

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer for you, but it may be the answer for you.

We downgraded our version of doorkeeper and it solved the problem. march2019

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/732